# What are the differences between Apple Thunderbolt Displays during their production years from 2011 to 2016?

Tags: thunderbolt-display

I need to buy a refurbished Thunderbolt Display to use with my (late 2015) MBP. I would like to know what are the **differences between Thunderbolt Displays that were produced during 2011-2016?**

Comment: @klanomath Can you make that an answer?

Comment: @klanomath I was just in the process of editing that out, I think your answer fits perfectly now! Not that I’m always in the habit of editing a question to fit an answer, but here asking for the technical differences is an interesting on-topic question and asking for current prices/sellers is very much off-topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only two "models" have been produced:

1. MC914LL/A (July 2011 - ~July 2012)
2. MC914LL/B (July 2012 - June 2016)

The only difference between the two models is an additional [MagSafe to MagSafe 2 converter](https://www.apple.com/shop/product/MD504LL/A/magsafe-to-magsafe-2-converter) which was shipped with the latter model. It allows to charge MagSafe 2-equipped Mac computer. The actual displays are the same.